# accessing all of my elements in a multi-dimensional array with multiple loops. Why is this coming out as undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Here's what I have, I have a 3-dimensional array with variations of my name. The whole thing looks like this.

```
var array = [['kenny', 'Kenney'],['ken','Ken'],['kenneth', 'Kenneth']];
```

Now, there's nothing wrong with it from what I can tell but then comes what I would like to do. I'm just trying to utilize a for loop to just loop through all of this at once so all of these elements show up. Here's what I wrote down for myself..

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < array.length[i]; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < array.length[i][j]; k++) {
            console.log(array[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
};
```

What comes back is undefined. What exactly am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance, guys.

Comment: The above array is 2 dimensional and you are doing 3-dimentional access. The code would work if the example was encased in `[ [ [ ... ] ] ]`

Comment: You only need to do 2 for loops

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues here. First, you are trying to go 3 "levels" deep as if this was a 3-dimensional array, but it is only 2-dimensional.

You also need to do `array[i].length` instead of `array.length[i]`

```js
var array = [
  ['kenny', 'Kenney'],
  ['ken', 'Ken'],
  ['kenneth', 'Kenneth']
];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    console.log(array[i][j]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the indexes in the wrong spot:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < array[i][j].length; k++) {
            console.log(array[i][j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

The last loops is not needed, because that will go through the words in each of your items, printing word for word each element.

Comment: Just copy-pasting OP code, but yes, only two fors are needed

Answer (score 0):

Each element of the first array has to be treated as an array.

```
var array = [['kenny', 'Kenney'],['ken','Ken'],['kenneth', 'Kenneth']];

for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `forEach` is clearer:

```js
var array = [['kenny', 'Kenney'],['ken','Ken'],['kenneth', 'Kenneth']];

array.forEach(function(subarray) {
  subarray.forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name);
  });
});
```